# Using :hover to change text displayed entirely?

Tags: css

I have... Found no other forum I can ask for some input on this through. I've been editing the CSS of a webpage for a friend of mine, who wants the title's text to change when hovered over. The problem is, I've been having an absolute hell of a time trying to get :hover to work for the title. I'm not sure whether or not I should try and rip it up and re-code it, considering it was a "theme" she found, (which might prove even more of a headache) or if someone might know how to get the text to change.

What she wants is to be able to hover over her title, "Veoleth Dathgir," and have it change to a different word, but no amount of putzing around with it has given me the result needed.

I should add that I have no professional experience with this. I've learned through a few years worth of hobby. So considering this a learning experience- How should I effect the change I need to add? I've been searching and searching for a good hour or two through here, google, w3schools, etc, and... not really gotten anywhere.

Entire page's worth of code [here](https://pastebin.com/ymN979ak), and some of the relevant lines here:

```
    .title {
  font-family:'apple chancery',uppercase; /*title font*/
  font-size:30px;
  padding-top:90px;
  text-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.subheader {
  margin-top:10px;
}

.header {
  width:550px;
  height:200px;
  -webkit-transition:ease-in-out .5s;
  -moz-transition:ease-in-out .5s;
  -o-transition:ease-in-out .5s;
  transition:ease-in-out .5s;
  text-align:center;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  color:#271717;
  border-bottom:solid #381F1F 20px;
  background-color:#423535;
  background-image:url();
  background-position:center;
  background-size:100% auto;
}

.header:hover {
  letter-spacing:3px;
  text-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}
```

and

```
<div class="header">
<div class="title">Veoleth Dathgir</div>
<div class="subheader">Spurned Ghosts</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the HTML?

Comment: You can't modify it with using css. CSS if for styling the HTML. Use Javascript or Jquery.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it. I can generally edit everything in the pastebin code provided to my heart's content. I've gotten the hover-change to work on a different page altogether, but the formatting on that one was a lot more simplified and grouped-together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you should use jQuery for that. Add this to the bottom of your body element in your HTML, just before the end to add jQuery to your site (if you don't already utilize it)...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then I would add an ID to the title, something like this...

```
<div  id="thisTitle" class="title">Veoleth Dathgir</div>
```

Then your jQuery would look like this, you can add it right to your HTML, at the bottom of your body tag like so...

```
<script>
//when you mouse over, change the text
$('#thisTitle').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).text('anythiny you want');
});
//when you mouse out, change it again to original (or anything)
$('#thisTitle').mouseout(function(){
  $(this).text('Veoleth Dathgir');
}); 
</script>
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/wade-labs/pen/QqNaMO, feel free to "export", the option is located in the lower right corner.

Comment: This worked like a charm- Thank you, I'm not as skilled with jQuery and this was actually really helpful! I've already got some ideas to play around with that and learn some more.

Comment: jQuery is really fun! And uses CSS selectors, so if you're already good at CSS you'll enjoy it that much more ;). Good luck and glad I could help!!